# How to install and configure HSQL DB on ubuntu 16.04 Machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm making a simple CRUD  application. My requirement is to use HSQLDB for JDBC. I need to install and configure HSQLDB to connect my project to thedatabase.

Since a couple of days, I  have been trying to install and configure it on my machine, but I am not able to configure and run it. I searched on the Internet for finding the solution on it and also went through the HSQLDB documentation. I'm confused by the documentation and I'm having trouble to understand it, and I felt that its little bit tough to understand for people like me.

I have no idea how to make it work on my machine? I hope that I will be able to find the right solution here

Documentation Link: http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlDocsFrame.html

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want to achieve and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some steps on how to download and run HSQLDB on Ubuntu.

1. Download and extract the zip from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/);
2. Run the server:

   ```
   $ java -classpath lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server &
   ```
3. Run the GUI manager:

   ```
   $ java -jar lib/hsqldb.jar &
   ```

Comment: it throws me an error: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hsqldb/server/Server has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0. Can you help me?